# How to use a Weibull distribution in a GLM in R?

Tags: r, distribution, glm, weibull

I am conducting a GLM on my data and found that a Weibull distribution would be the best fit to my data. However, this distribution does not seem to be available in the GLM selection. Is there any way to move around this and to still use the Weibull distribution in a GLM?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: See this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225457/fit-glm-for-weibull-family).